# Can you see which user handled/proces which customer order?

Tags: magento2, database, customer, user

Is it possible to see which user completed a customer order?

Answer (score 2):

First you need to create a plugin.

di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
  <plugin name="sales_order_grid_collection" type="VENDOR\MODULE\Plugin\OrderGridCollection" sortOrder="100" /> 
</type>
```

Create plugin file in VENDOR/MODULE/plugin/OrderGridCollection.php

```
<?php namespace VENDOR\MODULE\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface as MessageManager;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection as SalesOrderGridCollection;

class OrderGridCollection
{
    private $messageManager;
    private $collection;
    protected  $adminSession;

    public function __construct(MessageManager $messageManager,
        SalesOrderGridCollection $collection,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $adminSession
    ) {

        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->collection = $collection;
        $this->adminSession = $adminSession;            
    }

    public function aroundGetReport(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $requestName
    ) {
        $result = $proceed($requestName);
        if ($requestName == 'sales_order_grid_data_source') {
             $current_adminuser =   $this->adminSession->getUser();
        }

    }
}
```